# Basic JS/HTML Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I am trying to make a completely basic calculator with JavaScript and HTML. I haven't completely finished it yet but none of my buttons are working.

```js
function NumberClicked(numValue) {
 //alert(numValue);
 document.getElementById("calcInput").value += numValue;
}

function ClearAll() {
 document.getElementById("calcInput").value = '';
 document.getElementById("calcOutput").value = '';
}

function Add() {
 var output = document.getElementById("calcOutput");
 output.value = Number(document.getElementById("calcInput").value) + Number(output.value);

 document.getElementById("calcInput").value = '';
}

function Subtract() {
 var output = document.getElementById("calcOutput");
 output.value = Number(document.getElementById("calcInput").value) - Number(output.value);

 document.getElementById("calcInput").value = '';
}

function Divide() {
 var output = document.getElementById("calcOutput");
 if (output.value == "") {
  output.value = document.getElementById("calcInput");
 } else {
  output.value = Number(output.value) / Number(document.getElementById("calcInput").value);

 }
 document.getElementById("calcInput").value = '';
}

function Multiply() {
 //var 
}
```

```html
result<input id="calcOutput" type="text">
<br>
input<input id="calcInput" type="text">
<br>
<button onclick="ClearAll();">clear</button>
<br>
<button onclick="NumberClicked(7);">7</button>
<button onclick="NumberClicked(8);">8</button>
<button onclick="NumberClicked(9);">9</button>
<button onclick="Divide();">/</button>
<br>
<button onclick="NumberClicked(4);">4</button>
<button onclick="NumberClicked(5);">5</button>
<button onclick="NumberClicked(6);">6</button>
<button onclick="Multiply();">*</button>
<br>
<button onclick="NumberClicked(1);">1</button>
<button onclick="NumberClicked(2);">2</button>
<button onclick="NumberClicked(3);">3</button>
<button onclick="Subtract();">-</button>
<br>
<button onclick="NumberClicked(0);">0</button>
<button onclick="Add();">+</button>
<br>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2ffgtuxv/)

Comment: I added a Fiddle demo to your question. You can see that the buttons do in fact work. Please clarify your question to explain exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @isherwood, don't use JSFiddle on here anymore, you should use the Code Snippet instead.

Comment: @PrestonS there's no reason not to use JSFiddle, Snippets are just a convenience thing

Comment: You can press `F12` and check if you have any errors. I'm also afraid this will not quite behave like a normal calculator.

Comment: @PatrickEvans there are [numerous, documented reasons why snippets are preferable to fiddles](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). There are times when snippets cannot match the power of fiddles, but this is not one of them.

Comment: my teacher requires us to use jsFiddle im not sure why, and also this is the exact code he wrote in class and told us just to finish it, my computer wont let me push any of the buttons.

Comment: There must be some difference between your code and what has been posted. You've got two runnable examples now, one here as a runnable snippet, and one on jsFiddle.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function c(val) {
    document.getElementById("d").value=val;
}

function math(val) {
    document.getElementById("d").value+=val;
}

function e() {
    try {
        c(eval(document.getElementById("d").value))
    }
    catch(e) {
        c('error')
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="display"><input type="text" readonly size="18" id="d"></div>
    <div class="keys">
        <p>
            <input type="button" class="button gray" value="mrc" onclick='c("not defined")'>
            <input type="button" class="button gray" value="m-" onclick='c("not defined")'>
            <input type="button" class="button gray" value="m+" onclick='c("not defined")'>
            <input type="button" class="button pink" value="/" onclick='math("/")'>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" class="button red" value="7" onclick='math("7")'>
            <input type="button" class="button red" value="8" onclick='math("8")'>
            <input type="button" class="button red" value="9" onclick='math("9")'>
            <input type="button" class="button pink" value="*" onclick='math("*")'>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" class="button red" value="4" onclick='math("4")'>
            <input type="button" class="button red" value="5" onclick='math("5")'>
            <input type="button" class="button red" value="6" onclick='math("6")'>
            <input type="button" class="button pink" value="-" onclick='math("-")'>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" class="button red" value="1" onclick='math("1")'>
            <input type="button" class="button red" value="2" onclick='math("2")'>
            <input type="button" class="button red" value="3" onclick='math("3")'>
            <input type="button" class="button pink" value="+" onclick='math("+")'>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" class="button red" value="0" onclick='math("0")'>
            <input type="button" class="button red" value="." onclick='math(".")'>
            <input type="button" class="button red" value="C" onclick='c("")'>
            <input type="button" class="button orange" value="=" onclick='e()'>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I almost downvoted because there was no explanation, just code. I made this into a runnable snippet because I was curious about the results. There are some bugs but it actually runs pretty well. If you can fix the bugs and add some explanation as to why this is an answer it will be worthy of an upvote.